# spring-amqp implementation of RabbitMq - does it internally use queueDeclarePassive?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We are migrating from existing classic queues to quorum queues and one of the requirements is that we must declare queue usage as "passive" (i.e. queueDeclarePassive). The intent is to ensure we do not create any queues dynamically and only check for its existence (and fail if it doesn't exist) and then connect.

We have a legacy service that uses spring-amqp and we set the SimpleMessageListenerContainer like so:

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queue().getName());
```

...

```
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createChannel(false);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

I don't see a way to declare the queue as "passive". In reading the spring.io documentation, I see a description for declarationRetries:

"The number of retry attempts when passive queue declaration fails. Passive queue declaration occurs when the consumer starts or, when consuming from multiple queues, when not all queues were available during initialization."

Does this imply that spring-amqp uses queueDeclarePassive behind the scenes? Is this explicitly documented anywhere? If I'm incorrect, how do I properly ensure queueDeclarePassive is used within this amqp usage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this imply that spring-amqp uses queueDeclarePassive behind the scenes?

It doesn't **imply** it, it explicitly states it.

`queueDeclarePassive` is used by the listener containers during startup to verify the configured queue(s) are present.

By default, the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` will try 3 times at 5 second intervals, and if the passive declarations fail, the container will stop. The number of attempts and interval can be configured.

The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` will try indefinitely to passively declare the queue(s) if they don't exist, using its `monitorInterval` property.

Spring AMQP will only perform non-passive queue declaration (queue creation) if the application context contains `Queue` `@Bean`s and there is a `RabbitAdmin` `@Bean` present.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why this was so hard for me to find.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/_introduction.html
"When the listener container consumers start, they attempt to passively declare the queues to ensure they are available on the broker."

Comment: It probably wouldn't have made a difference, but why are you looking at 7 year old documentation (and for a pre-release at that)? You should always go to the project page for the latest docs https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#learn That said, it is still not clear to me why you think that sentence is not clear that passive declaration is used.

Comment: If you're really curious, I was looking for a more direct statement like "Passive declaration is used by default" (or will always be used) as opposed to just using it as part of the sentence I quoted to talk about retries. Either that was the case or I failed to find the right section in the documentation that states this as clearly as I was hoping for.